# Geth error with HTTP JSON RPC and urllib python3

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, python

I try to run this (geth is started with rpc on http://localhost:8545)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
rpc = "http://localhost:8545"
print(urlopen(Request(rpc,urlencode({"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":42}).encode(),headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}), timeout=60).read().decode())
```

It print :
`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"invalid character 'j' looking for beginning of value"}}`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [web3.py](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to interact with your ethereum node from 
 python. Web3.py will take care of these connection and encoding issues for you.